# Oracle SQL Developer unable to export schema and data by Export Wizard

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am using Oracle Sql Developer to export schema and data ,
tool > Database Export >

[image]

[image]

[image: No Tables Found on look up]

[image: After Export No schema generated]

After Export there empty schema generated

[image: select * from user_tables;]

Comment: Most likely answer is your user doesn't actually own any tables. What does select * from user_tables; show?

Comment: select * from user_tables;
it shows all my tables

Comment: Update your question please with this info...I want to see your tables list from that query

Comment: @thatjeffsmith updated screenshot in my question

Comment: I'm trying to see if you are logged in as sys or system...

Comment: i have used a new user created , not from sys or system

Comment: Also tried in sys and system login also 
Actually i have deleted default tables in system login , is that cause any issues ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240017/discussion-between-jeebendu-kumar-behera-and-thatjeffsmith).

Comment: Was this resolved?  I have same issue

Comment: @JeebendukumarBehera asking someone to continue the conversation in a private chat totally defeats the entire purpose of stackoverflow and is not helpful in any way for other people

Answer (score -1):

Need to make sure the database connection you selected has not been dropped.  Right click on connection and select reconnect before exporting.